# Place caret below anchor text

Tags: html, css

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-decoration: none">
        <span class="criteria">any</span>
        <span class="caret" style="margin-top:6px;"></span>
</a>
```

The above piece of code is giving me the following output 
`any ▼`

How to place the caret below the anchor close to the anchor text.

Approx look :

```
any
 ▼
```

EDIT : I have text following the anchor and caret, but I want it to be on same line.

```
before anchor text any text following the anchor
                    ▼
```

The any is basically a drop down in the middle of sentence. So I want the caret to be close to anchor text, but below it and not necessarily as a next line

EDIT 2 : code before and after

```
     <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls dropdown">
            Create backup if
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-decoration: none">
                <div class="criteria">any</div>
                <div class="caret" style="margin-top:6px;display: inline-block"></div>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="selector"
                style="text-decoration: none;left: 18%;min-width: 65px;">
                <li><a title="any">any</a></li>
                <li><a title="all">all</a></li>
            </ul>
            of the following are true:
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try change `<span>` to a `<div>` for the caret only?

Comment: can you post your css?  if you give `.caret` a `display:block` declaration you should have more flexibility

Comment: I have a text following up this anchor. Its going into the next line if I use div.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of before and after the anchor? hard to solve it w/o the added context

Comment: @user2133404 Check the edit on my answer, now I think that it exactly what you want.

Comment: @ochi added entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take on it...  Notice that, as you add text before -or after-  the caret follows the anchor

```css
.caret {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: -1.2em;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 0;
}

a > .caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls dropdown">
    Create backup if more code here
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-decoration: none">
      <span class="criteria">any</span><span class="caret">^</span></a> of the following are true:
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated to remove extra spaces**

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your caret like this:

```
<span class="caret" style="position:absolute; margin-top:15px;margin-left:-20px;"></span>
```

That's the final look and the snippet:

```html
 Nothing to see there<br>
 If  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="text-decoration: none">
       <span class="criteria">any</span>
       <span class="caret" style="position:absolute; margin-top:15px;margin-left:-20px;">^</span>
</a> unicorns are watching you, be happy!
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of absolute, can you please tell me if we can position it relative to criteria span